# How do you send a raw strings through a jQuery POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, post

I am trying to POST a raw string via jQuery.ajax()

e.g.,

```
contact_list=352345
```

I have

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', header);
        }
        },
        url: link,
        type: type,
        processData:false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
     });
```

*Most* of the time I am sending JSON data, so `header='application/json'`

On the server side, I echo `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and see my JSON string just fine.

However, I sometimes want to send normal form data too.  But when I set `header='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is empty.

`ProcessData` is false, so shouldn't it just pass my string on through?

As a temporary workaround I'm just leaving the header as `application/json` and ignoring the `Content-Type` on the server for this particular endpoint.

Comment: What is really boggling my mind, is that in the network inspector it looks like the request payload went through properly.  e.g., contact_list=352345 is there... Maybe this is a PHP thing and form data doesn't show up in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

So, now on the server I do the following:

```
if (count($_POST == 0){
    $raw = file_get_contents('php://input');    
}else{
    $raw = '';
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $raw = $raw.$key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
}
```

Seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

No extra work needed. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> processDataBoolean:
>
> Default: true By default, data passed in to the data option as an
>   object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed
>   and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default
>   content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send
>   a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'm curious as to why it's not sending my string through for this header type but it is for application/json.

Comment: @speg. Didn't that solve the issue? I didn't understand what you wrote.

Comment: Not sure, I'm in bed now :). Will try in the morning.  I meant, why am I able to see HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA when the header type is application/json abut not for application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  It's as if jquery is altering it for the later case, even though processData is still false.

Comment: I had seen that, and interpreted it as "jQuery won't touch your data if you set this to false".  Which is what I had done.  However, in either case I am just passing a string.  It's only when I set the header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' does jQuery remove my data.

Comment: @speg. Are you sure it's removed? can't you see that string with firebug?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather send a flag to my javascript function to see what sort of input

so your function will look like this

```
function processIt(request_type,link,type,data) {
if(request_type == 'json')
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', header);
    }
    },
    url: link,
    type: type,
    processData:false,
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
else 
 $.ajax({
url: link,
data: data,
success: function(data){
    //do something
}
 });
}
```

But that's if you want to use your function as it is.

Comment: I sort of ended up doing this, but I still can't set the header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.  If I do it doesn't pass my string through.  Ideally I would like to able to set this for server-side purposes...