# opening dynamic php page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script that create user specific pdf files. (mpdf)

To download the file without losing the current page i used ajax.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(multydimarray);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "gen.php",
  data: {data : jsonString}

  success: function(response){
   window.location = "gen.php";
  }
});
```

But gen.php wasn't received any data from ajax. $_POST['data'] wasn't set So,

File was downloaded, Current page stayed untouched, but the file was empty.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the ajax request's contentType to `application/json; charset=utf-8`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "gen.php",
  data: {data : jsonString}
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

  success: function(response){
   window.location = "gen.php";
  }
});
```

then get the data in PHP like this

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Sry, i didnt mentioned. var jsonString = JSON.stringify(multydimarray);

Comment: i couldnt understand this php part. will data become multidimarray ? 'php://input' with this

Comment: @user2102266, json contentType requests are not parsed into $_POST. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147599/how-do-you-send-a-raw-strings-through-a-jquery-post-request